Fixing differential equation for boundary conditions
I have a nonlinear differential equation of the real univariate scalar function $f$:
$$f\frac{\mathrm{d}^2f}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2$$
or more concisely $f’’(x)f(x)=f’(x)^2=f’(x)f’(x)$. I know that on its own $e^x$ is a solution to this equation because $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^x= \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}e^x=e^x$, so
$$f \frac{\mathrm{d}^2f}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=e^x(e^x)=e^{2x}=(e^x)^2=\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2.$$
This is all well and good; however I would like to establish boundary conditions such that
$$f(x)=0\,\text{for}\,x>a$$
and
$$f(x)=p\,\text{for}\,x<b$$
for finite positive reals $a$, $b$, and $p$ where $a>b$. Here I considered a piecewise function that uses two exponentials to approximate the boundary conditions well but it led to a non-removable discontinuity in the second derivative, and I can’t think of any other possibilities. I can also remove the second condition and replace it with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f=0$ if there are no solutions with these current conditions but that is less than desirable.
Is there a general way to find solutions to this nonlinear differential equation that satisfy the boundary conditions?

For the sake of tradition, more than anything, I'm going to denote $f$ by $y$. Solving this equation in general is not difficult. We can, in most circumstances, write it as:
$$\frac{y''}{y'} = \frac{y'}{y}, \tag{$\star$}$$
Why do I say "in most circumstances"? There is a problem if $y$ or $y'$ is $0$ at a given $x \in \Bbb{R}$. It doesn't mean the equation is unsolvable, just that the method won't work if this is the case. So, let us assume that we have some $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $y(x_0) \neq 0$ and $y'(x_0) \neq 0$.
Since both $y$ and $y'$ are differentiable and hence continuous (at least at this point $x_0$), there exists some interval $[x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta]$, where $\delta > 0$, on which $y(x)$ and $y'(x)$ are non-zero. On this interval, we can continue our analysis.
Taking the integral of both sides of $(\star)$ with respect to $x$ yields
$$\ln|y'| = \ln|y| + C$$
for some constant $C$, which further implies $y' = Ay$ for some constant $A$. The solutions to this equation are well known to be:
$$y = Be^{Ax}$$
for some $B$. So, this solution will hold on the interval $[x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta]$.
Now, we can conclude, since $y$ is non-zero on this interval, that $B \neq 0$. If we consider the largest possible interval, containing $x_0$, where this formula is appropriate, it would be all of $\Bbb{R}$. If it weren't, and it had, say, an upper bound, then continuity would show that the interval would have a maximum $x^*$. But then, $y(x^*) \neq 0$ and $y'(x^*) \neq 0$ once again, and so we could find $A', B'$ such that $y = B' e^{A'x}$ for points close to $x^*$. Looking to the left of $x^*$ would show that $A = A'$ and $B = B'$, while looking to the right, we would see that $x^*$ was not an upper bound after all. So, no maximum would exist, and a similar proof would work for the minimum.
All of this is to say, once you have a single point $x_0$ where $y(x_0) \neq 0$ and $y'(x_0) \neq 0$, then you have the solution $y = Be^{Ax}$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$, for some $A, B$, where $B \neq 0$. As such, in this case, $y \neq 0$ and $y' \neq 0$ everywhere.
If, on the other hand, we had a point $x_0$ where either $y'(x_0) = 0$ or $y(x_0) = 0$, then we must therefore have $yy' = 0$ everywhere on $\Bbb{R}$. By integrating both sides with respect to $x$, we obtain $\frac{1}{2}y^2 = C$ for some $C$, which implies $y = \pm \sqrt{C}$ for all $x$. But, if $C \neq 0$, continuity demands $y = \sqrt{C}$ for all $x$, or $y = -\sqrt{C}$ for all $x$. Or if $C = 0$, we get $y = 0$ for all $x$. In any case, $y$ is constant, which still fits within the $Be^{Ax}$ form: we take $A = 0$, and $B$ can be the constant.
So, all in all, after being way too careful, we therefore know that there exists some $A$ and $B$ such that
$$y(x) = Be^{Ax}$$
for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$.
This, of course, poses a problem for you. You could expect $f$ to constantly be $0$ when $x > a$, or you could expect $f$ to be constantly $p > 0$ for $x < b$, but you can't have both at the same time.
Even just expecting a solution where $f(x_0) = 0$ and $f(x_1) = p$ for some $x_0, x_1$ will be problematic. Having $f(x_0) = 0$ tells us that $B = 0$, and the constant $0$ function is the only solution. You either have no roots, or you have all of the roots!
Replacing the constantly $0$ condition doesn't help either, if you insist that the function be constantly $p$. You can, however, have the function be $p > 0$ somewhere, but limit to $0$ as $x \to \infty$, so long as $A$ is chosen to be negative.
I hope that helps.

That does help significantly, thank you. I can ignore the latter condition to make solutions easier to find anyways so this is perfect.
